# "$.fieldValue is not a function" alert on login form submit

Tags: 7, javascript, users

In Drupal 7, with Devel, CTools and Ajax Login/Register plugins, I get an alert on submitting the login form on http://p262957.mittwaldserver.info/drupal/user/login.

I am using a custom child theme based on bootstrap project. I already tried the instructions on https://www.drupal.org/node/1008664 that says I should be sure to load jquery.form.js before ajax.js.

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the parent theme was a ajax.js override function that caused the error. It can be found in theme_root_dir/js/misc/. You just have to empty it. Don't forget to empty your cache afterwards. Now it should work.

Comment: I have tried your way, issue has been fixed but ajax functionality is not working now. Is it right way to make changes in drupal core files?